# How to make API call for weibo using omniauth in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, weibo

My code is,

```
 consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(app_key, app_secret, { :site => "http://api.weibo.com", :scheme => :header })

 request_token = consumer.get_request_token

 token_hash = { :oauth_token => request_token.params['oauth_token'], :oauth_token_secret => request_token.params['oauth_token_secret'] }

 access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(consumer, token_hash)

 feeds = access_token.request(:get, '/2/account/get_uid.json?source=app_key')
```

But, i'm getting the following error

```
 {"error":"token_rejected!","error_code":21317,"request":"/2/account/get_uid.json"}
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Hi did you find a solution to this problem? I am trying to achieve something similar.